# How to get multiple images from url and place them in separate div in javascript one by one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to place images one by one horizontally on my website. It place the image one after the another and i dont want it. I want to place the image one by one horizontally on the particular space to look beautiful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="flockler_container"></div>
    <div id="flockler_container1"></div>
    <div id="flockler_container2"></div>
    <div id="flockler_container3"></div>
    <script>
        var _flockler = _flockler || {};
        _flockler.count = 20;
        _flockler.refresh = 0;
        _flockler.site = '1239/14550';
        _flockler.style = 'wall';

        (function(){var f = document.createElement('script');
        f.async=1;
        f.src='http://embed-cdn.flockler.com/embed-v2.js';
        s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];


        s.parentNode.insertBefore(f,s);
       })();

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Make your div inline-block editing their css style="display: inline-block;".

Comment: its putting all the images in one line but i want to place them seprately one by one in line

Comment: But i am getting images from the flockler widgit so how to get timage one by one into my div. It put all the images in one line. As i am getting images in one array.

Answer (score 0):

You can float the images/divs to get displayed horizontally side by side.

**Html**

```
<div id="flockler_container img-float"></div>
<div id="flockler_container1 img-float"></div>
<div id="flockler_container2 img-float"></div>
<div id="flockler_container3 img-float"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
   .img-float{
      float:left;
      width:25%;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: But i am getting images from the flockler widgit so how to get timage one by one into my div

Comment: But i am getting images from the flockler widgit so how to get timage one by one into my div. It put all the images in one line. As i am getting images in one array.

Comment: there are four images in one array of line. I try to loop through it to get one by one image but not succeded.  (function(){var f = document.createElement('script');
        f.async=1;
        f.src='http://embed-cdn.flockler.com/embed-v2.js';
        s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];


        s.parentNode.insertBefore(f,s);
       })();